# How to enable/disable push notification from my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, push-notification, remote-notifications

I'm working on App that have push notification property. And I should enable/disable the push notification permission **within** my app **without go to iPhone settings.**

Is there a way to implement that?

I searched a lot, but I didn't find any proper way to implement it.

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a user denied permissions for push notifications you can not let him enable it from within the app.

You could however, set a button in your settings app (`ViewController`), and let the user switch the notifications off and on there. Then you can set a boolean to check before sending notifications. This way a user might use it instead of disabling the app's notification permission on the device settings.

Answer (score 2):

#### Enable Push Notification (Setup from app):

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // SETUP FOR NOTIFICATION FOR iOS >= 10.0
            let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.delegate = self
            center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
                if error == nil{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                    }) 
                }
            }
        }else{
            // SETUP FOR NOTIFICATION FOR iOS < 10.0

            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.sound, .alert, .badge], categories: nil)
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

            // This is an asynchronous method to retrieve a Device Token
            // Callbacks are in AppDelegate.swift
            // Success = didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
            // Fail = didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
```

#### Delegate methods to handle push notifications

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // ...register device token with our Time Entry API server via REST
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    //print("DidFaildRegistration : Device token for push notifications: FAIL -- ")
    //print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

#### Disable Push Notifiacation:

```
UIApplication.shared.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()
```